# what is the name of this exercise machine nunes is using to exercise punches?

Tags: exercise-equipment

what is the name of this exercise machine nunes is using to exercise punches?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having read your question, I was interested in finding out what type of equipment is being used in the picture you posted.  While I'm not an MMA fan, I am interested in different types of exercise equipment.  So, with a little bit of detective work, I was able to determine that Amanda Nunes trains out of the [American Top Team](https://americantopteam.com/virtual-tour/) Facility in Coconut Creek Florida.  The screen cap you posted does not provide a full perspective of machine, and, with it's position near other treadmills, I initially suspected that it was some form of tread stepper.  However, after watching her work out, I realized that she trains exclusively for her sport using specific equipment.  That led me to investigate further and I found this:

[image]

And, since gyms are typically organized with similar equipment grouped together on the floor, I took a chance that the machine was from the company that makes [Real Runner](http://www.tigerbarbell.com/) and it was.

[image]

The machine is actually called a [Torque Machine](http://www.tigerbarbell.com/Torque-Machine_p_14.html) that was designed to...

> “work the whole body through a complete push and pull resistance
>   motion, utilizing resistance in the modes of both flexion and
>   extension. “

She's obviously adapted its usage to fit her training for MMA.

Comment: Nice find on the research! Kudos!